# ERROR: Could not do lightweight checkout, falling back to heavyweight

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

ERROR: Could not do lightweight checkout, falling back to heavyweight
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No file present at location jenkins/Jenkinsfile
at com.atlassian.bitbucket.jenkins.internal.scm.filesystem.BitbucketSCMFile.content(BitbucketSCMFile.java:83)
at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFile.contentAsString(SCMFile.java:335)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.SCMBinder.create(SCMBinder.java:108)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:311)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)

> git rev-parse feature/CSGAUTO-1469^{commit} # timeout=10
> ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
> ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting

Finished: FAILURE

Does anyone know the solution to this issue

It's a multibranch pipeline.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.